# How to calculate the minimum value over the last 5 years of some data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using [this data](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/WCESTUS1w.xls) which is a data on US oil stocks each week.
So column A is the date, and column B is the value
I would like to add two new columns C and D that are :

- The minmum value at a given date over the last 5 years
- The maximum value at the same given date over the last 5 years

I have first set the A column do date format and the play a bit with the MINIFS and MAXIFS functions but have not managed to do anything sucessful

Comment: [Check this link I've edited in your File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C16H8CvH5tmCUWvVLjK6syI9Yw6CBjrG/view?usp=sharing) ☺ Or [You may check this also](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s28q70xjny8yngt/WCESTUS1w.xls?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarize your question first.
In the spreadsheet you provided, column A (A4:A1968) consists of current dates, column B (B4:B1968) has an appropriate prices to the given date.

Now the formulas:

1. You need to calculate the date (now minus 5 years). Place this formula into cell C4, expand the formula across rest of C columns.

   =DATE(YEAR(A4)-5, MONTH(A4), DAY(A4))
2. To calculate Minimum price over last 5 years, use this formula into cell D4 and press **"Ctrl+Shift+Enter"**. Drag the formula into every D row.

   =MIN(IF((A$4:A$1968<=A4)*(A$4:A$1968>=C4),B$4:B$1968,""))
3. To calculate Minimum price over last 5 years, use this formula into cell E4 and press **"Ctrl+Shift+Enter"**. Drag the formula into every E row.

   =MAX(IF((A$4:A$1968<=A4)*(A$4:A$1968>=C4),B$4:B$1968,""))

[The result should look like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8aFl.png)

Tell me if it works for you